# jQuery not working - strange

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('works');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        alert('does not work');
    });
    ​
</script>
```

Very strange, I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: i ran it on http://www.jsfiddle.net/ and working fine !!!

Comment: I had some issues working with CDN locally

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the function should be [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) <del>and not [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) (this sends an AJAX request):</del>

```
$(window).ready(function () {
```

Also make sure you understand the distinction between `$(document).ready` and `$(window).ready`. The first will be triggered when the DOM is ready while the second when the DOM and all images are ready.

Answer (score 1):

It should work after all images, css and scripts are loaded. Is there something that is taking too long to load?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

```
$(function() {
    alert("does work");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options for what you're trying to achieve:

1. `$(function() { alert('works'); });`
2. `$(document).ready(function() { alert('works'); });`

It's up to you which one you use. Personally I prefer the shorthand code in option 1 but there's a readability advantage with the second option.

Answer (score 0):

youe are doing window.load which waits for every thing to get loaded before executing. however you should use DOM ready function of jQuery.

```
jQuery(function(){
    //do something
});
```